# How do I rewrite /projects/* to /content/projects/*

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite `/projects/*` to `/content/projects/*`

I really don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(projects/.*)$ /content/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. It's giving me an Error 404 File Not Found.

Comment: Move this rule to line #21 in your htaccess

Comment: But now my Stacey cms site doesn't load http://desbest.uk.to/projects properly like it does http://desbest.uk.to/work It's supposed to show a html page.

Comment: Do you still want `/content/projects/*` to be routed to `/index.php` or `/public` ?

Comment: No I want `projects/*` to be routed to how the Stacey cms normally routes it by finding a file in the `/templates/` folder and filling it with the variables in `/content/projects` and it automatically routes folders and subfolders based on what I put inside `/content/`. I also want `projects/*` to be routed to `/content/projects/*`